How to have SSIS Logging On Remote DB
I have built an SSIS solution in Visual Studio 2022, running on Windows 11 Professional, the packages pull data from a remote SQL Server DB (2022) and cleanse\process the data and write to another remote SQL Server DB (2022). All the packages work fine in my local Visual Studio, and I am trying to build in logging in case of any problems and auditing etc before I deploy the packages on the same server as the remote destination SQL server DB. I have followed the two guides in below URL's as these seem good, also using these guides, if I create an additional connection to my local SQL server (2022) and setup logging there it seems to work fine. I force an error in one of the packages and the details are saved to dbo.sysssislog in the System Tables location as expected when the destination is the local SQL server.
However, when I set up the logging to connect to the DB in the remote destination SQL Server DB and run the package with an error, the dbo.sysssislog is not created anywhere and so no logging processed. What is causing the problem here please? It is probably a basic configuration I am missing
I tried following these two guides on SSIS logging
https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-ssis-package-logging/
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4070/integrated-logging-with-the-integration-services-package-log-providers/
I am expecting the dbo.sysssislog table to be created in System folder in destination database but it is not creating the table and recording errors.
